# Toggle class on click body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know lot of questions something like this are also in Stackoverflow. Here is a bit of Jquery problem. I have added toggle class Jquery function, and the same class should be remove when click anywhere on the body. Its working now, but I no need toggle that class when we click inside of the input text field.

Code:

```js
var removeClass = true;
$(".btn-search").click(function() {
  $(".input-search").toggleClass('expanded');
  removeClass = false;
});
$("html").click(function() {
  if (removeClass) {
    $(".input-search").removeClass('expanded');
  }
  removeClass = true;
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.col-search {
  padding: 13px 8px 8px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.input-search {
  width: 220px;
  height: 34px;
  max-width: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  bottom: 13px;
  right: 46px;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

.input-search.expanded {
  max-width: 220px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-search {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 38px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 0;
  background: #333;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-search">
  <input class="input-search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="button" class="btn-search" value="click">
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/3a84p6h0/

Comment: I think you can just stop propagation in your input click handler so the click event does not bubble up to the html

Comment: Just replace `$("html").click(function() {` to `$("button").click(function() {` to prevent toggle

Comment: You could expand and focus the search field when the button is clicked.  Then when the search field loses focus you could remove the class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix this you can check which element raised the click event that bubbled up the DOM. If it was not within the `.col-search` then you can toggle the class.

Also note that this logic makes your `removeClass` variable redundant.

```js
$(".btn-search").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".input-search").toggleClass('expanded');
});

$("html").click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.col-search').length == 0)
    $(".input-search").removeClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.col-search {
  padding: 13px 8px 8px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.input-search {
  width: 220px;
  height: 34px;
  max-width: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  bottom: 13px;
  right: 46px;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

.input-search.expanded {
  max-width: 220px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-search {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 38px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-search">
  <input class="input-search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="button" class="btn-search" value="click">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes.. it is simple and Great !!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to check the event wasn't triggered by the input you want to exclude using [**event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

This also doesn't interfere with other events that might be bound to the input itself.

```js
var removeClass = true;
$(".btn-search").click(function() {
  $(".input-search").toggleClass('expanded');
  removeClass = false;
});
$("html").click(function() {
  var searchInput = $(".input-search");
  if (removeClass && event.target != searchInput[0]) {
    searchInput.removeClass('expanded');
  }
  removeClass = true;
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.col-search {
  padding: 13px 8px 8px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.input-search {
  width: 220px;
  height: 34px;
  max-width: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  bottom: 13px;
  right: 46px;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

.input-search.expanded {
  max-width: 220px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-search {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 38px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 0;
  background: #333;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-search">
  <input class="input-search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="button" class="btn-search" value="click">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just alter your JS with event on the input with return value
https://jsfiddle.net/fcdo7kyh/

```
    var removeClass = true;
$(".btn-search").click(function() {
  $(".input-search").toggleClass('expanded');
  removeClass = false;
});
$(".input-search").click(function() {
  return false;
});

$("html").click(function() {
  if (removeClass) {
    $(".input-search").removeClass('expanded');
  }
  removeClass = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following code:

HTML:

```
<input class="input-search" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="inputSearch" />
```

JS:

```
$("#inputSearch").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
var removeClass = true;
$(".btn-search").click(function() {
  $(".input-search").toggleClass('expanded');
  removeClass = false;
});
$("html").click(function() {
  if (removeClass) {
    $(".input-search").removeClass('expanded');
  }
  removeClass = true;
});
$("#inputSearch").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.col-search {
  padding: 13px 8px 8px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.input-search {
  width: 220px;
  height: 34px;
  max-width: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  bottom: 13px;
  right: 46px;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

.input-search.expanded {
  max-width: 220px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-search {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 38px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 0;
  background: #333;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-search">
  <input class="input-search" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="inputSearch" />
  <input type="button" class="btn-search" value="click">
</div>
```

Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".navbar-toggler").on("click", function(e) {
    $("body").toggleClass("openMenu");
    e.stopPropagation()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
  data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
  aria-expanded="false" 
  aria-label="Toggle navigation"
>
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

sweet and simple

```js
$(".btn-search").click(function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
  $(".input-search").toggleClass('expanded');
});
$("html").click(function() { 
    $(".input-search").removeClass('expanded'); 
});
$(".input-search").click(function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
  $(".input-search").addClass('expanded');
 
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.col-search {
  padding: 13px 8px 8px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.input-search {
  width: 220px;
  height: 34px;
  max-width: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  bottom: 13px;
  right: 46px;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

.input-search.expanded {
  max-width: 220px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

.btn-search {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 38px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 0;
  background: #333;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-search">
  <input class="input-search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="button" class="btn-search" value="click">
</div>
```

Comment: While it works it is far from **simple** seeing you now have added more moving parts to the solution. Also, having `$(".input-search")` **always** show itself when clicked is making `$(".input-search")` "aware" how it is being used outside of it's own logic and responsibilities. `$(".input-search")` shouldn't have to worry about how some other process wants to use it.